# Regex to get string between curly bracket tags in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex

$HTML:

```
{list:start:Data}
   {id} is having a title of {title}
{list:end:Data}
```

**Data** is dynamic and could be any string.

I am trying to loop all the occurences with the following code:

```
preg_match_all('/\{list:start:(.*?)\}(.*?)\{list:end:(.*?)\}/', $HTML, $match);
```

I want the following result:

```
$match = array(
   array(
      "string" => "Data",
      "value" => "{id} is having a title of {title}"
   )
);
```

but I get the follow result:

```
$match = array(
   [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
        )
);
```

but that isn't working as $match returns an empty array. After a few hour of searching for a solution I am still no closer to a working result.

Comment: Can you please provide sample values so that your question has a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? And also please expand on "not working" - what exactly happens?

Comment: @El_Vanja please see updated question. Thank you

Comment: It's still not clear to me what is going on here. `$HTML` is supposed to be a string, so how do you expect an array to be inside it?

Comment: What does a var_dump of `$HTML` give you?

Comment: Please see updated question, I have simplified it. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to cross lines that start with `list:` https://3v4l.org/shT5S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the braces, and use `/s` to match more than single line. Below is the code example.

---

## Code

```php
<?php

$input = '
{list:start:Data}
   {id} is having a title of {title}
{list:end:Data}

{list:start:Data1}
   {id1} is having a title of {title1}
{list:end:Data1}

{list:start:Data2}
   {id2} is having a title of {title2}
{list:end:Data2}

{list:start:Data3}
   {id3} is having a title of {title3}
{list:end:Data3}

';

preg_match_all(
    "/\\{list:start:(.+?)\\}(.*?)\\{list:end:(.+?)\\}/s",
    $input,
    $preg_matches
);

$matches = [];
foreach ($preg_matches[1] as $k => $v) {
    $matches[] = [
        "string" => trim($v),
        "data" => trim($preg_matches[2][$k])
    ];
}

print_r($matches);
```

---

## Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [string] => Data
            [data] => {id} is having a title of {title}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [string] => Data1
            [data] => {id1} is having a title of {title1}
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [string] => Data2
            [data] => {id2} is having a title of {title2}
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [string] => Data3
            [data] => {id3} is having a title of {title3}
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can make use of a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) instead of using `.*?` with the `/s` modifier to have the dot match a newline.

If you don't want to match consecutive lines that start with `{list:` you can use a negative lookahead rules out those matches.

```
^{list:start:([^}]+)}\R((?:(?!{list:).*\R)*+){list:end:[^}]+}
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `{list:start:` Match literally (Note that the `{` does not need to be escaped)
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^}]+` Match 1+ times any char except `}`
- `)` Close group 1
- `}` Match the closing `}`
- `\R` match any unicode newline sequence
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:(?!{list:).*\R)*+` Repeat matching all lines as long as they not start with `list:`
- `)` Close group 2
- `{list:end:` Match literally
- `[^}]+` Match 1+ times any char except `}`
- `}` Match the closing `}`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JLRRWT/1) and a [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/shT5S).

Example code

```
$re = '/^{list:start:([^}]+)}\R((?:(?!{list:).*\R)*){list:end:[^}]+}/m';
$str = '{list:start:Data}
   {id} is having a title of {title}
{list:end:Data}

{list:start:Data}
{list:start:Data}
   {id} is having a title of {title}
this is some text
{list:end:Data}';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

print_r(array_map(function($x){
    return [
        "string" => $x[1],
        "data" => trim($x[2])
    ];
}, $matches));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [string] => Data
            [data] => {id} is having a title of {title}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [string] => Data
            [data] => {id} is having a title of {title}
this is some text
        )

)
```